# How Javascript Class property are made unaccessible?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, sapui5

I'm using the framework  SAP UI5. I'm creating an instance of a class

//sap.m.Button is a javascript class

```
var myButton = new sap.m.Button({text:"Hello"});
console.log(myButton.getText());             //Hello
console.log(myButton.getProperty('text');    //Hello
console.log(myButton.text);                  //undefined
```

Why myButton.text is undefined ? How is the class implemented such that property cannot be accessed directly rather only by the methods provided by the class ?

Comment: It's likely that they store the options object that you pass to the constructor is some pseudo-private member which is then used to access the text property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more likely that they store the options variable as an instance property, and define the methods on the prototype of the constructor.

```
function Button(opts){
     this.opts = opts;
}

Button.prototype = {
    constructor: Button,
    getText: function() { return this.opts.text; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the property of object by doing this for example

```
var button = function(opts){
  /* private data */
  var text = opts.text;

  this.getText = function(){
    return text;
  }
}

var bb = new button({ text: "Hello" });
// bb.text == undefined
// bb.getText() == "Hello"
```

Comment: It is correct but not efficient. It's a bad practice to define shared members on each instance individually.

Comment: its just example how you can do it))

Comment: Yes but that's a really but practice; and it should be avoided

Comment: can you give links to improve my knowledge about this points, good practices?

Comment: Just read anything that has to do with the prototype chaining mechanism in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

What you do here is pass an object to the constructor of the class `sap.m.Button`. What happens with that object in the constructor is up to the implementation. It doesn't necessarily has to add them to the object. In this case they are likely stored in a local variable of the object. The constructor likely looks something like this:

```
sap.m.Button = function(properties) {
    var text = properties.text; // private variable only visible in the scope of the class

    this.getProperty(key) { // public function - as denoted by the prefix "this."
        if (key == 'text') {
            return text;  // returns the value of the private variable
        }
        // ... and more code for other properties ...
    }

    // ... and much more stuff ....
}
```

But you can add public variables to an object later:

```
var myButton = new sap.m.Button({text:"Hello"});
myButton.myVariable = "foo";
colsole.log(myButton.myVariable); // outputs "foo"
```

Comment: Why would someone define a shared method on each instance? That's not a good  practice at all.

Answer (score 1):

Properties of a managed object should only be accessed via the mutator or accessors provided eg [getText](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Button.html#getText), if you really want to access them directly try

```
myButton.mProperties.text
```

Comment: ManagedObject is a UI5 thing: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html